# weird user agent flag "x-middleton"

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, logging, nginx, user-agent

I often see in my webservers logs the “x-middleton” flag from amazon IP's ranges and looks like normal traffic (there is a variety of user agents but they all share that x-middleton at the end )

Anyone has any ideas what it might be ?

I came across this link http://support.ezoic.com/hc/en-us/articles/206245065-Origin-Errors-and-other-error-messages- but its not that it makes much sense either.

Comment: No, the link you found doesn't make a lot of sense, but then again, nothing on that site makes much sense... but it does seem related.  Are you using that service (whatever it is)?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot nope i'm not , its just thats the only place where i found an x-middleton reference

Comment: You're saying "user agent" but it seems like you're talking about HTTP headers in general (of which `User-Agent` is only one of many possible).  Can you add a specific example to the question?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot whats this "x-middleton” ? that is the question

Comment: I get it.  Show the complete headers from a request, please.  It may make more sense in context.

Comment: 54.160.115.203 - - [11/Sep/2016:17:45:09 -0400] "GET /rihanna-hit-that-won-the-2013-best-music-video-grammy-3-wds/ HTTP/1.1" 200 51530 "https://www.google.ca/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13G36 Safari/601.1 X-Middleton/1"
@Michael-sqlbot normal logs, there is a limit here but logs look like that

Comment: X-Middleton is ezoic's proprietary ad-optimizing proxy server. Your site must be running behind ezoic. Check your domain's NS records, they probably point to ezoicns.com

Answer (score 5):

Ezoic adds it to user agents when it proxies traffic.